# <legend> not centering in Firefox

Tags: css

In my CSS, I did:

```
legend{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Still the `legend` is left aligned in Firefox. It works properly in Chrome. The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006824/how-to-center-the-legend-element-what-to-use-instead-of-aligncenter-attribu) does not work for Firefox.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5JeaQ/14/

**UPDATE:**
I do not want to do `width: 100%` as it looks ugly with that.

I am using Firefox v26.

Comment: Add some width - `legend{width:100%};`

Comment: It looks ugly with that.

Comment: It worked for me. Added some width for clarity: http://jsfiddle.net/5JeaQ/15/

Comment: @Ruddy What version are you using? I am on v26.

Comment: @RahulDesai Im using the same. v26.0

Comment: Updated my answer with an actual fix.

Comment: `#container{ text-align: center; }` is what aligns it in my firefox.

Comment: @Ruddy Using plain `html` fixes it: `<legend align="center">Phone Directory</legend>`

Comment: @BeatAlex Well from what I can see there is no problem. Also using plain `HTML` isn't really the best. Using `CSS` would be better. but good job finding a fix.

Comment: @Ruddy Thanks :). For some reason your fix didn't work for me in firefox. I have no idea why. The `html` fix is easier to have as it will then align in all browsers. Although yeah, it's not the best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier than we thought.

It can be accomplished in all browsers using plain HTML.

```
 <legend align="center">Phone Directory</legend>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wttLJ/1/)</kbd>

Comment: @RahulDesai, ok will look into it.

Comment: I was actually avoiding to use inline styling, but it seems thats the only way to go. Thank you for your answer. :)