# HTML align legend element in the center doesnt work in internet expl and firefox

Tags: html, css, css-float

i wanted to place an image at the center of legend . Here is the link http://codepen.io/e6z6a6z/details/IJnoF .. this is working fine in chrome but in firefox and internet explorer the image is floating to the left. I tried giving my legend with 100% an keeping it text-align center but then the border-top goes away..i want the same border-width and image in between..PLease help

Comment: You should post ypur code, not just a link. And what IE versions are you trying on?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006824/how-to-center-the-legend-element-what-to-use-instead-of-aligncenter-attribu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `align="center"` `attribute` to **legend tag**.

Comment: The align attribute is not officially supported for <legend> http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-legend-element

Answer (score 0):

You must give the element, which have the text-align: center; 100% width and it must be a block-element. After this, the elements inner the container should be centered.

```
legend {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```