# Text on div border with transparent background

Tags: html, css, background-image, transparent

How to put some text on a `border div` so that text has a `transparent background` that it matches the image behind?

The problem is that the  `background-image` has some **shapes** and **multiple colors**, so I can't put just some background color the the text because it won't fit.

Example:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(http://wallpoper.com/images/00/45/05/47/green-background-2_00450547.jpg);
}
#main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#main h2 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -40px 0 0;
  background: transparent; /* somehow remove the border behind the text */
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h2>Star players</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crp3kfxj/)

Comment: @downvoter if this is a simple task, please be free to post the answer.

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/uprkj7kj/

Comment: @Dmitriy it's a good solution but as I can se, it doesn't want to `text-align` in FF?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cmwshx90/  FF work - legend - align:center

Comment: @Dmitriy isn't `align` deprecated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006824/how-to-center-the-legend-element-what-to-use-instead-of-aligncenter-attribu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a fieldset instead of a div:

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Test</legend>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
legend {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: best , straight forward answer. good

Comment: This solution solved my problem, tnx.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to see one thing 2 layers behind the text but not the other thing that is between the two...that in itself is rather counter-intuitive.  Not sure you will be able to do it unless you use a border image and css gradient which is always a little complicated and this won't be dependant on the size/width of the text.

e.g.

HTML

```
<div class="gradborder-box"><div class="inner"><h2>Hello WORLD</h2></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.gradborder-box{
margin: auto;
  width: 350px;

  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid transparent;

  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 68%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 26%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 68%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

h2{font-size: 1.2em; text-align: center; margin-top: -10px;}
.inner{height: 150px; width: 100%; border-bottom: 2px solid #000; margin-bottom: -2px;}

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNWZBE)

This has been done for CHROME - you will need to add in the correct border image tags for the other browsers  (-moz-border-image, etc).  This is CSS3 only.

Comment: The "inner" div is put in place to add the solid bottom border, without it the bottom border would look like the top.  Might be possible to change the gradient to a radial or something to avoid that but that gets really fiddly.  Hopefully get you on a decent track though.

Comment: Oh and you won't get rounded corners that way, sorry.

Comment: Oh or just use fieldset as stated by @KittMedia .....best answer.